# pandas multi index sort directly

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I asked this question: [pandas multi index sort specific fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200897/pandas-multi-index-sort-specific-fields) as a follow up I would like to improve a little bit and perform the sorting directly with multi indices:

Here is a sample df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'modelName':['model1','model1', 'model2', 'model2'],
                           'scoringValue':[7,8,9,7]})
```

Which results in the following overview

```
overview = df.groupby([df.modelName]).describe().unstack(fill_value=0).loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, ['mean','std']]]
print(overview)

          scoringValue          
                  mean       std
modelName                       
model1             7.5  0.707107
model2             8.0  1.414214
```

I want to sort the models by `mean` of scoringValue, but retain the grouped relationship to `std`

This could be achieved by

```
overview.columns = ['{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format(tup) for tup in overview.columns]
overview.sort_values('scoringValue_mean', ascending=False)
```

But I rather would like to work directly with the Multi-index (nicer visual representation) and get a result like this one:

```
          scoringValue          
                  mean       std
modelName                       
model2             8.0  1.414214 
model1             7.5  0.707107
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using [DataFrame.sort_index(level=1)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)?

```
In [77]: overview.sort_index(level=1, ascending=0)
Out[77]:
          scoringValue
                  mean       std
modelName
model2             8.0  1.414214
model1             7.5  0.707107
```

Comment: great! Thanks again.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler, sure! It was a perfect question - very clear and fully reproducible (including python code) - good job! :)